# Tried to install xdebug there is no zend_extension in php.ini file

Tags: php, php-ini, xdebug-profiler

I tried to install xdebug in windows 10. There is no zend_extension in php.ini file. I followed this way:

```
Download php_xdebug-2.9.5-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
Move the downloaded file to
Edit C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line.
```

but I couldn't find zend_extension .

Comment: Well if the dll was moved to correct location and php.ini adjusted all that may be missing is the reloaded of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes php drops this error however everything seems fine in phpinfo. Check the phpinfo whether the xdebug session is present.

Answer (score 0):

You are *adding that line* so it won't exist *yet*.

Your php.ini file should have this added to it:

```
; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = c:\xammp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.5-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

Make sure you put that DLL in the ext directory as well.

(I guessed at the path to the PHP extension directory as I do not use xampp.)

Comment: Hi @thavaranjanmayurathan. If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.